# Want to display only specific value in graph's x-axis , but its showing repeated values of columns of csv-file

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

I need to display only unique values on x-axis, but it is showing all the values in a specific column of the csv-file. Any suggestions please to fix this out?

```py
df=pd.read_csv('//media//HOTEL MANAGEMENT.csv')
df.plot('Room_Type','Charges',color='g')
plt.show()
```

Comment: We need an example of that data and a desired output.

Answer (score -1):

My assumption is that you are looking to plot the result of some aggregated data. e.g. Either:

- The total charges per room type, or
- The average charge per room type, or
- The minimum/maximum charge per room type.

If so, you could so like:

```
df=pd.read_csv('//media//HOTEL MANAGEMENT.csv')

# And use any of the following: 
df.groupby('Room_Type')['Charges'].sum().plot(color='g')
df.groupby('Room_Type')['Charges'].mean().plot(color='g')
df.groupby('Room_Type')['Charges'].min().plot(color='g')
df.groupby('Room_Type')['Charges'].max().plot(color='g')
```

Seeing that the x-axis may not necesarily be sequential, a comparative bar graph could be another way to plot.

```
df.groupby('Room_Type')['Charges'].mean().plot.bar(color=['r','g'])
```